# How rotate all logs in glassfish?

Tags: glassfish

I can push rotate button from "Server" menu item, but it rotates only server.log file, while others files int logs folder are not touched. Is there a way to rotate all?

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour. The current log file is rotated/archieved and a new log is created. The old logs are kept to look them up later. From the  [official Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1751/givwx/):

> Logs are rotated automatically based on settings in the
> logging.properties file. You can change these settings by using the
> Administration Console.
>
> You can rotate the server log file manually by using the rotate-log
> subcommand in remote mode.
>
> This example moves the server.log file to
> yyyy-mm-dd_server.log and creates a new server.log file in the default
> location.

If you want to restrict the number of log files to keep you can try to set the system property `com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.max_history_files`, which specifies the maximum number of log files to keep (more info [here](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/GlassFish/FaqDeleteRotatedLogs)).